# Why can't fontawsome icons be exported to PDF or word files?

Tags: icons, font-awesome

I am displaying icons from fontawesome (https://fontawesome.com/v4/icons/)

The image on the browser is fine but it will not show on PDF or doc files when exported.
For example copying the screen (ctrl-c) and pasting into a word document shows everything except the the icons.
Is there a way to export these icons?

Answer (score 0):

PDF cannot use Fonts Unless they are in an Acceptable Font Table, and as a commercial set only a limited number are free
[image]

Here is the way a PDF Character is mapped. On the left is the index entry used for placement, then in the middle is its Unicode value, then I have added those symbols in FontAwsome Plain Text (some times these non viewable symbols are called MojiBake, but its often a misnomer as each one in this case is distinctly different)

```
endcodespacerange
4 beginbfchar
<000F> <F002> = 
<02A2> <F2CD> = 
<02A9> <F2D5> = 
<02AE> <F2DA> = 
```

How they are seen by a PDF editor is no different the "TEXT" is an unknown blob of pictorial ink, and only if the symbol is well defined as a pictogram can it also look like an Ideogram.

[image]
[image]

They WILL work (if TTF is good) in a document, here even in most basic Notepad

[image]

A PDF editor can handle those symbols same as any other HTML editor so here I copy pasted several times as plain text but an extractor would simply see more unknown box shapes

[image]

Hence as advised the easiest way for Doc(X) is use a TTF variant and that will Print as PDF

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue. But you know, for this and other reasons I prefer to use iWork (Apple Pages, Numbers and so on). I am using the version 6.4 for desktop, and I will tell you the compatibility chart according to my experience.

I worked a document in PAGES using the Header and Footer tools, which have the equivalents in MS Word. I, first of all SAVE the document as Pages.

Then, exported to PDF and MS Word. Also it happened in Photoshop, unbelievable, few days ago, but later it worked (the next day), maybe it was a slow connection with the CDN, i Don‘t know but worked.

If I continue with MS Word is because I receive lots of documents in word and managing the icons for a nice conversion to PDF is really a nightmare. Check the pics, good luck.[image: Apple PAGES: Icons rendered upon typing without problems][image: Icons rendered in PDF upon export; however, you can not generate an FA-icon just typing directly.][image: Apple exported to MS-Word. Pasting the svg or inserting through insert image command, you can get the SVG file generate by Fontawesome, but not typing as a font icon.]

By the way, have you tried the version 6? I noticed that when a new version or subversion appears, sometimes they don‘t work properly.